# Graphql-net server in an azure function doing subscriptions with signalR

Tags: graphql, azure-functions, graphql-subscriptions, azure-signalr

Looking for sample code to do have a **graphql-net server** living in an **azure function** endpoint and doing **subscriptions**. Azure functions don't support WebSockets so thinking at using **signalR**.

According to https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/subscriptions/ graphql-net does support subscriptions but using Appollo graphql subscription protocol.

According to https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/server/issues/289 it should be doable, but it has been doable for 3 years and I have not found any more detail.

Thank you.